# how to install hybridauth in zend framework 2 manually

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php, hybridauth

The title is self explaining.
How to Install **hybridauth** ind **zend** framework 2 manually, I mean without composer.

I've copied hybridauth folder in vendor folder but when I want to use `ScnSocialAuth` module , this error happens :

PHP Fatal `error:  Class 'Hybrid_Auth' not found in /home/public_html/mysite/vendor/ScnSocialAuth/src/ScnSocialAuth/Service/HybridAuthFactory.php on line 34`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your composer.json looks like that ?

```
{
    "name": "you/application",
    "description": "My App",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.7.*",
        "zf-commons/zfc-user": "0.1.*",
        "
        "socalnick/scn-social-auth": "1.10.*",      
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Hybrid": "vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/"
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise add classes to **autoload_classmap.php**

```
'Hybrid_Providers_px500'                                                                => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-500px/Providers/px500.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Disqus'                                                               => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-disqus/Providers/Disqus.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Draugiem'                                                             => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-draugiem/Providers/Draugiem.php',
    'DraugiemApi'                                                                           => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-draugiem/thirdparty/Draugiem/DraugiemApi.php',
    'Draugiem_Api'                                                                          => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-draugiem/thirdparty/Draugiem/DraugiemApi.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_GitHub'                                                               => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-github/Providers/GitHub.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Goodreads'                                                            => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-goodreads/Providers/Goodreads.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Google'                                                               => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Google.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Identica'                                                             => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-Identica/Providers/Identica.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Instagram'                                                            => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-instagram/Providers/Instagram.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_LastFM'                                                               => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-lastfm/Providers/LastFM.php',
    'LastFMException'                                                                       => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-lastfm/thirdparty/LastFM/LastFM.php',
    'LastFMInvalidSessionException'                                                         => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-lastfm/thirdparty/LastFM/LastFM.php',
    'LastFM'                                                                                => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-lastfm/thirdparty/LastFM/LastFM.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Mailru'                                                               => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-mailru/Providers/Mailru.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Murmur'                                                               => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-murmur/Providers/Murmur.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Odnoklassniki'                                                        => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-odnoklassniki/Providers/Odnoklassniki.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Pixnet'                                                               => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-pixnet/Providers/Pixnet.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Plurk'                                                                => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-plurk/Providers/Plurk.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_QQ'                                                                   => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-qq/Providers/QQ.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Sina'                                                                 => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-sina/Providers/Sina.php',
    'OAuthException'                                                                        => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-sina/thirdparty/Sina/saetv2.ex.class.php',
    'SaeTOAuthV2'                                                                           => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-sina/thirdparty/Sina/saetv2.ex.class.php',
    'SaeTClientV2'                                                                          => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-sina/thirdparty/Sina/saetv2.ex.class.php',
    'WeiboOAuth'                                                                            => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-sina/thirdparty/Sina/Sina.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Skyrock'                                                              => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-skyrock/Providers/Skyrock.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Steam'                                                                => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-steam/Providers/Steam.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Tumblr'                                                               => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-tumblr/Providers/Tumblr.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_TwitchTV'                                                             => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-twitchtv/Providers/TwitchTV.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Viadeo'                                                               => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-viadeo/Providers/Viadeo.php',
    'ViadeoException'                                                                       => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-viadeo/thirdparty/Viadeo/ViadeoAPI.php',
    'ViadeoSDKException'                                                                    => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-viadeo/thirdparty/Viadeo/ViadeoAPI.php',
    'ViadeoInvalidConfigurationException'                                                   => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-viadeo/thirdparty/Viadeo/ViadeoAPI.php',
    'ViadeoOAuth2Exception'                                                                 => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-viadeo/thirdparty/Viadeo/ViadeoAPI.php',
    'ViadeoAuthenticationException'                                                         => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-viadeo/thirdparty/Viadeo/ViadeoAPI.php',
    'ViadeoAPIException'                                                                    => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-viadeo/thirdparty/Viadeo/ViadeoAPI.php',
    'ViadeoConnectionException'                                                             => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-viadeo/thirdparty/Viadeo/ViadeoAPI.php',
    'ViadeoRequest'                                                                         => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-viadeo/thirdparty/Viadeo/ViadeoAPI.php',
    'ViadeoGraphObject'                                                                     => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-viadeo/thirdparty/Viadeo/ViadeoAPI.php',
    'ViadeoAPI'                                                                             => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-viadeo/thirdparty/Viadeo/ViadeoAPI.php',
    'ViadeoHelper'                                                                          => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-viadeo/thirdparty/Viadeo/ViadeoAPI.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Vimeo'                                                                => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-vimeo/Providers/Vimeo.php',
    'phpVimeo'                                                                              => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-vimeo/thirdparty/Vimeo/Vimeo.php',
    'VimeoAPIException'                                                                     => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-vimeo/thirdparty/Vimeo/Vimeo.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Vkontakte'                                                            => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-vkontakte/Providers/Vkontakte.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_XING'                                                                 => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-xing/Providers/XING.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Yahoo'                                                                => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Yahoo.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Yandex'                                                               => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/additional-providers/hybridauth-yandex/Providers/Yandex.php',
    'application'                                                                           => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/examples/signin_signup/application/base.php',
    'model'                                                                                 => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/examples/signin_signup/application/base.php',
    'controller'                                                                            => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/examples/signin_signup/application/base.php',
    'authentications'                                                                       => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/examples/signin_signup/application/controllers/authentications.php',
    'home'                                                                                  => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/examples/signin_signup/application/controllers/home.php',
    'pages'                                                                                 => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/examples/signin_signup/application/controllers/pages.php',
    'users'                                                                                 => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/examples/signin_signup/application/controllers/users.php',
    'authentication'                                                                        => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/examples/signin_signup/application/models/authentication.php',
    'user'                                                                                  => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/examples/signin_signup/application/models/user.php',
    'Hybrid_Auth'                                                                           => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php',
    'Hybrid_Endpoint'                                                                       => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php',
    'Hybrid_Error'                                                                          => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Error.php',
    'Hybrid_Logger'                                                                         => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Logger.php',
    'Hybrid_Provider_Adapter'                                                               => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Provider_Adapter.php',
    'Hybrid_Provider_Model'                                                                 => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Provider_Model.php',
    'Hybrid_Provider_Model_OAuth1'                                                          => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Provider_Model_OAuth1.php',
    'Hybrid_Provider_Model_OAuth2'                                                          => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Provider_Model_OAuth2.php',
    'Hybrid_Provider_Model_OpenID'                                                          => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Provider_Model_OpenID.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_AOL'                                                                  => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/AOL.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Facebook'                                                             => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Facebook.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Foursquare'                                                           => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Foursquare.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_LinkedIn'                                                             => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/LinkedIn.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Live'                                                                 => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Live.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_MySpace'                                                              => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/MySpace.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_OpenID'                                                               => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/OpenID.php',
    'Hybrid_Providers_Twitter'                                                              => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Twitter.php',
    'Hybrid_Storage'                                                                        => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Storage.php',
    'FacebookApiException'                                                                  => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/Facebook/base_facebook.php',
    'BaseFacebook'                                                                          => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/Facebook/base_facebook.php',
    'Facebook'                                                                              => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/Facebook/facebook.php',
    'LinkedInException'                                                                     => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/LinkedIn/LinkedIn.php',
    'LinkedIn'                                                                              => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/LinkedIn/LinkedIn.php',
    'OAuthExceptionPHP'                                                                     => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth.php',
    'OAuthConsumer'                                                                         => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth.php',
    'OAuthToken'                                                                            => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth.php',
    'OAuthSignatureMethod'                                                                  => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth.php',
    'OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1'                                                        => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth.php',
    'OAuthSignatureMethod_PLAINTEXT'                                                        => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth.php',
    'OAuthSignatureMethod_RSA_SHA1'                                                         => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth.php',
    'OAuthRequest'                                                                          => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth.php',
    'OAuthServer'                                                                           => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth.php',
    'OAuthDataStore'                                                                        => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth.php',
    'OAuthUtil'                                                                             => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth.php',
    'OAuth1Client'                                                                          => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth1Client.php',
    'OAuth2Client'                                                                          => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth2Client.php',
    'LightOpenID'                                                                           => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OpenID/LightOpenID.php',
    'Hybrid_User'                                                                           => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/User.php',
    'Hybrid_User_Activity'                                                                  => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/User_Activity.php',
    'Hybrid_User_Contact'                                                                   => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/User_Contact.php',
    'Hybrid_User_Profile'                                                                   => __DIR__ . '/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/User_Profile.php',
```

Comment: He wants to go without composer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add this line on the `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php`

```
'Hybrid' => $vendorDir . '/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/'
```